# How to auto insert values in dependency table?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-normalization

I have created three tables. One is named as `User` and second is `Folder` and third one is `User Folder Rights Table` . I have inserted values in table by using Query

`Insert into Users values ('admin','123');`

`Insert into Folders values ('folderA');`

[image]

Third table is Normalized Table and dependent on both these tables. As i executed these above defined queries, Nothing stores in third table `User Folder Rights Table` shown in this above image.

What is the reason of this behavior and secondly how to automatically generate values in this `Third` Table when these two above explained queries will execute?

*If my question is not clear to you please ask me.*

Comment: So you want entries for every user, and every folder, in your folder rights table. Any time a new user or folder is created, you want missing rows to be inserts into the Folder rights table? I'd suggest an after insert trigger on both the user and folder tables, that runs a cross join to the other to find the missing ones.

Comment: @Bridge yes i want this. How to add triggers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Triggers to achieve this goal. Please follow this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server) . It has detailed description.

Thank's
Tameen.

Comment: thank you ... can you please describe me Instead Of Triggers ?

Answer (score 1):

You must be missing the sequence of insertion , First of all insert values into independent tables e.g User,Folders then take the latest Primary Keys and insert them into third normalized form.

Its even more good you use triggers, but that will lead you in a bit complex workload.